# What are some things that only Jedi Masters could do, and not new Jedi Knights (or Padawans)?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jedi-training

Was the difference in the things that a Jedi Master could do with the Force and the things a newly-Knighted Jedi Knight could do, simply a matter of practice and familiarity?

Did promotion to Knight mean that the Jedi Padawan already knew all skills that a Jedi Master would know, with the difference in level simply a matter of practice-making-better-the-skills-you-already have; or does canon give us any skills that were reserved to be learnt only by Masters or experienced Knights?

If yes, what are some of these Master/experienced Knight-level Force-skills according to canon?

Comment: My take from it was just that the Masters were better versed in the ways of the Jedi - Some, like Yoda, understood and could use the force at a level above anyone else. Another Master may be better with a lightsaber, someone else may possess superior tactial knowledge or diplomatic ties with different races & people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the sourcebook "[The Jedi Path: A Manual for Students of the Force](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Jedi_Path:_A_Manual_for_Students_of_the_Force_(real-life_book))" the  answer is that the *title* of Jedi Master is precisely that, a title.

This honorific can be gained in a variety of ways:

- By undertaking a more advanced version of the Jedi Trials
- By taking on a teaching position at the Jedi Temple
- By mentoring one or more Padawan learners (typically the title of Master would be conferred when your first Padawan is accepted as a full Knight)
- By showing extraordinary service to the Republic in some fashion
- By special dispensation of the Jedi Council (Anakin was expecting this and was [vexed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1lukQMmdiE) not to receive their recognition).

There don't seem to be any additional mysteries that you're inducted into when you become a Master, nor are there any obvious force talents that are off-limits to mere knights.

Comment: Just to point out, even though this is an old answer: while meritorious service to the Republic could gain one the title of Jedi Master, that decision was still up to the Council, not the Republic Senate.  This was a key point in the Revenge of the Sith movie - Anakin was given a place on the Council (by Palpatine appointing him as a representative) but was NOT made a Master.

Answer (score 2):

Being a **[Jedi Master](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Master/Legends)** vs. a [Jedi Knight](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Knight/Legends) seems to be primarily a point of experience & versatility. The moment that marks a Jedi Knight as ready for masterhood varies with each individual, but seems largely to depend on an understanding of the Force. Knighthood is concerned largely with the practical aspects of the Force, whereas Masterhood is more concerned with the philosophical aspects of its use.

Probably the earliest mention of this difference is Ulic Qel-Droma's death in [*Tales of the Jedi: Redemption*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_of_the_Jedi:_Redemption) some 4000 years before the movies...

[image]

Later references would be something like the scene from [*Legacy of the Force: Betrayal*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Force:_Betrayal) where Mara Jade has to do multiple tasks at once:

> Yes, any Jedi Knight might know one of these three techniques - most
>   commonly, the technique of levitation. But only a Jedi Master was
>   likely to know all three or be able to sustain them simultaneously
>   across such a broad distance.

... or the scene in the same novel where Luke asks Jacen Solo to undertake a seemingly suicidal mission and explains why he chose him instead of a master:

> Third, your specialized training in alternative philosophies of the
>   Force makes you more versatile than many other Jedi - than some Jedi
>   Masters, in fact -  making it harder to stop you.

Answer (score -1):

Found this in [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Master).  It seems that the process is quite arbitrary although it does require a certain level of devotion and knowledge of the Force.

> The rank of Master was a title bestowed upon very few Knights in every generation. As such, Masters made up the smallest percent of the Order's membership. The most common path to this rank was to train several Padawans as a Knight, typically one right after the other, and have them all successfully pass their Jedi Trials. If one did not wish to train several students, a Knight could choose to undergo a modified version of the Trials of Knighthood, or gain attention for their service to the Republic. Each of these feats could gain the High Council's acknowledgment and result in a promotion to the rank of Master.[1] When Luke Skywalker reformed the Order following the Great Jedi Purge, he promoted his students to the rank of Master based on their degree of mastery of the Force. As the Order began to grow, most Masters were promoted based on the extraordinary deeds they performed for the New Republic. One well known example was the promotion of Jedi Knight Kyle Katarn following the defeat of the Dark Jedi Desann at his blade.[2]

So in the case of some, it can be a greater knowledge of the Force in comparison to other Jedi's and in other cases it is based on extraordinary deeds.